# Django update_or_create (get part) using related object as kwarg

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm doing an update_or_create queryset operation, which internally uses the get queryset operation. I've read through the documentation on the update_or_create queryset method but I'm having some difficulty in understanding the parts relating to foreign keys and using objects as kwargs.

Consider an example where I have models Book and Chapter and I do something like this:

```
book = Book.objects.get(...)

kwargs = {'book': book, 'name': 'Chapter 3'}
defaults = {'text': '...'}
Chapter.objects.update_or_create(defaults=defaults, **kwargs)
```

Now the kwargs will be used in the 'get' method to check whether that chapter exists. But, since book is an object, how does Django know whether there is a chapter with a "matching" book? Does it check whether all fields of the book object match? Does it check only the unique field? Only the primary key of the book? If I have two books with the same fields but different primary key, could they match? Is it good practice to use an object in the kwargs in this way, or do I risk getting integrity error problems? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context, I am assuming that `Chapter` has a FK to `Book`.

In that chase, Django will use the field ID or, if you changed the default setup, the primary key from the book instance to match. It is the same as doing:

```
Chapter.objects.update_or_create(defaults=defaults, book=book.id)
```

So you have have hundreds of books with the exact same fields except the primary key, django will know how to handle it.

Comment: To be sure, I should then set my unique field to pk=True instead of letting Django assign a pk, if I want two books with the same unique field to be regarded as a match, correct?

Comment: You don't need to. Unless you really need to change the way the pk works, let Django deals with it. 

If you need to deal with unique fields, just add the flag `unique=True`, no need to change the pk. You can also take a look on `unique together`. See here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: Right they'll be the same anyway. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

here, `kwargs` is just a dictionary, when you are using `**` infront of it, it means the values are being unpacked and passed like this:

```
kwargs = {'book': book, 'name': 'Chapter 3'}
Chapter.objects.update_or_create(defaults=defaults, **kwargs)
```

Translates to(values being passed as keyword arguments):

```
Chapter.objects.update_or_create(defaults=defaults,book=book, name="Chapter 3")
```

Now, django matches book's primary key within chapter. If primary keys between 2 book objects are not same, meaning they are different objects regardless their other fields being same.